# How to fix overly blurred texture / image in unity?

Tags: android, libgdx, sprites, unity

so, I'm not sure what caused this, let image below do the explanation :
[image]
How to fix the overly blurred texture in unity? It's so frustrating, since I can't get it right, because when I tried it in LibGDX, the image looks good (Well, it's not exactly a same image, but similar).

They both screenshot from android device (Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo)

Thanks

P.S. It's a pixel art

Edit, here's the screenshot of my relevant inspector window

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

And here's the alpha ingame screenshot
[image]

Comment: Are you sure scale .75 is a good idea? Typically you want to leave sprites at full size (ie. scale 1) in order to see exactly the image with no interpolation.

Comment: @jhocking setting it to 1 doesn't do much help either

Comment: You showed the pixels-per-unit setting in one screenshot, but can we also see your camera settings? The camera needs to be correctly sized for a pixel-perfect display. basically what I explain here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75376/why-does-unity-in-2d-mode-employ-scaling-and-the-default-othographic-size-the-wa/

Comment: @jhocking added the main camera screenshot

Comment: Possibly related: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/

Comment: ok yeah your camera size is wrong. I'll explain in an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up Unity so that 2d images are displayed in their original resolution?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/119213/how-can-i-set-up-unity-so-that-2d-images-are-displayed-in-their-original-resolut)

Comment: just saw you saying below: "The unity remote view is blurred, while the built version is not." oof I *really* wish you had mentioned Unity Remote before; that is not actually running the game on your device. Do not rely on Unity Remote for testing graphics quality; personally I don't use it at all because it's misleading, but some people find Unity Remote convenient for testing UI stuff. To test graphics quality, actually build an apk and install the app on your device.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get pixel-perfect 2D graphics in Unity, you need to correctly set the size of the camera. I explain it in this other question:

[Why does Unity in 2d mode employ scaling and the default othographic size the way it does?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75376/why-does-unity-in-2d-mode-employ-scaling-and-the-default-othographic-size-the-wa/)

Long story short, set the camera to Orthographic (which you've done) and then set the Size to:

size of your screen / pixels-per-unit setting of your images / 2

Comment: gonna try it first, do not expect me to quickly accept it. But as soon as I make it work, I'll accept this ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, say my device testing screen height (using unity remote) is 1280 (my game is portrait). So then, 1280 / 100 / 2 = 6.4. But the image is still rendered blurred. Why?

Comment: Your pixels-per-unit is set to 50, not the default 100. Also you scaled the image to .75; I would recommend leave the scale at 1.

Comment: I see, fixed. But yet still slightly blurred compared to the original image. So, the recommended way to resize the sprite is via external image editor (Photoshop etc), and not via unity scale?

Comment: yes. and if it's still blurry, perhaps now you should try vitorino's suggestion about filter mode? That didn't work by itself, but it may help now that the camera is correctly sized.

Comment: where's that vitorino's suggestion about filter mode located? Googled up but didn't find any

Comment: sorry forgot you can't see it because he deleted it. it said "Try by unchecking Generate Mip Maps and as long as your filter mode is set to point, everything should be ok."

Comment: Actually tried it and did no notable differences. Idk what's wrong. I also tried with other non-pixel art image (from unity tutorial). And when I run it with Unity Remote in my android device, It also blurred.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird tho. The unity remote view is blurred, while the built version is not. I think it's because the unity editor resolution is somehow forced to fit the window size (even though I've defined 1280x720 manually, but still forced down to around 400ish pixel), because, when I build the apk version and installed it on my device, the picture no longer blurred. Not sure why. (I tried with a new clean project btw.). But I think the problem is not on the camera ortho size.

Comment: You should have said that you are using unity remote. let me explain how unity remote works. Its litteraly captures the game screen from the editor and sends a compressed stream to the device. Then it handles inputs from the device and sends them to the editor. The quality of the graphics is always going to be blurred when using unity remote. you can refer to [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120614/sprites-blurred-in-unity-filter-mode-set-to-point/120615#120615)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an obvious problem in the settings you show, but I have seen a similar blurring effect with unusually wide sprite sheets. The program Aseprite likes to export in one long sheet, like a film strip, and that is where I've seen it happen. When this has occurred for me, changing the *Max size* on the **sprite import settings** did not fix the problem. I had to edit my sprite sheet and make it more grid based.