# Sprites blurred in Unity (filter mode set to point)

Tags: unity, 2d, android

I'm new to Unity and I'm developing Android game. When I connect my phone with Unity Remote and launch game, all textured are blurred and they look awfull.

Did some research and set Filter mode to point as everyone suggested but that didn't work at all.

My sprite settings are as follows:
- Texture type: Sprite (2D and UI)
- Packing Tag: isn't set
- Pixels per unit: 100
- Pivot: Center
- Generate Mip Maps: unchecked
- Filter mode: point

Can anyone help me with this?

[image: So this is how it looks in Unity]

[image: And how it looks on Unity remote]

Comment: Can you paste screenshots, both source gfx and blurred one? Edit: What size is gfx and "Max size"?

Comment: It's up in first post

Comment: The size goes from 1020x244 for those play and exit buttons, and 512*512 for those for social media. Max size is default in program

Comment: Ok, try to set format to "Truecolor" on all of UI sprites and check than.

Comment: Oh and filter mode to Trilinear, sorry for spam.

Comment: No, still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38963/discussion-between-pawel-marecki-and-daxhr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity remote sends a compressed stream from the editor to your phone and then sends back the inputs from the phone to the editor. there is nothing you can do about it being bad quality. How ever this does not represent the final quality of the build. Try making a real build for android and check how it looks then.